# CoppeliaSim ZMQ Remote API Java client example not working

Tags: java, simulator, robotics

Hi I am trying to use the CoppeliaSim ZMQ Remote Api with Java: https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/zmq ... /main/java

I followed all the necessary steps to set up the API. Set up the simStubsGen, the ZMQ plugin and the set ups necessary for the Java client. The setup should be alright because I already have a Python client working.

But I just used the Java client from the Coppelia repository, without making any changes. And when I try to run it, I always get this error.

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
```

Besides, NetBeans identifies that there are more problems in the code.
In RemoteAPIClient.java, NetBeans identifies the following lines as errors:

```
80 this.send(req);
81 this.recv();


153 UnicodeString respFunc = (UnicodeString) rep.get(k_func);


163 co.nstant.in.cbor.model.Array v_args = new co.nstant.in.cbor.model.Array();

443 objs = new RemoteAPIObjects(this);

453 RemoteAPIObjects objs = null;
```

The last errors are because it is not recogniying RemoteAPIObjects as a data type (which is weird but I can solve). Also, there are other additional problems.

Also, in the class Example.java I still have the same problem in this line:

```
11 var sim = client.getObject().sim();

Because getObject() does not recogniye a method .sim()
```

Also note that the class RemoteAPIObjects.java is full of Python wrappers that so far have not worked.

Can someone please help me to make this Java client work.

Thanks.